# Toggle property of nested array of object - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects with 3 levels. I want to target the innermost child with property 'code'. If code is present, then update the child as well as the parent object with `selected: true`. If the property already is true, then sending in the same value should set the child to `selected: false` (toggle)
This is what I have going so far. If selected is true for a child, sending in another code should set `selected: true` for the corresponding child and `selected: false` for the child which had true for selected property.

Also, if selected is true for a child, defaultCollapsed property should be false for the child as well as parent and grandparent. Ifs elected is false for a child, defaultCollapsed property should be true for the child as well as parent and grandparent

```js
const data = [{
    "label": "Grand Parent 1",
    "index": 0,
    "code": "GRAND_PARENT_1",
    "defaultCollapsed": true,
    "items": [{
        "id": 1,
        "items": [{
            "id": 100,
            "label": "Child 1",
            "url": "#CHILD_1",
            "code": "CHILD_1",
          },
          {
            "id": 200,
            "label": "Child 2",
            "url": "#CHILD_2",
            "code": "CHILD_2"
          },
          {
            "id": 300,
            "label": "Child 3",
            "url": "#CHILD_3",
            "code": "CHILD_3"
          },
          {
            "id": 400,
            "label": "Child 4",
            "url": "#CHILD_4",
            "code": "CHILD_4"
          }
        ],
        "defaultCollapsed": true,
        "label": "Parent 1",
        "selected": true,
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "items": [],
        "defaultCollapsed": true,
        "label": "Parent 2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "items": [],
        "defaultCollapsed": true,
        "label": "Parent 3"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "items": [],
        "defaultCollapsed": true,
        "label": "Parent 4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Grand Parent 2",
    "index": 1,
    "code": "GRAND_PARENT_2",
    "defaultCollapsed": true,
    "items": []
  },
  {
    "label": "Grand Parent 3",
    "index": 2,
    "code": "GRAND_PARENT_3",
    "defaultCollapsed": true,
    "items": []
  }
]

function select(items, key, value) {
  if (!Array.isArray(items)) {
    return false;
  }

  for (const item of items) {
    if (item.code === value || select(item.items, key, value)) {
      item.selected = !item.selected;
      item.defaultCollapsed = false;
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

function reset(items) {
  if (!Array.isArray(items)) {
    return;
  }

  for (const item of items) {
    if (item.selected) {
      reset(item.items);
      item.selected = false;
      break;
    }
  }
}

function resetAndSelect(data, key, value) {
  reset(data);
  select(data, key, value);
}

resetAndSelect(data, 'code', 'CHILD_1')

console.log('CHILD_1',data)

resetAndSelect(data, 'code', 'CHILD_2')

console.log('CHILD_2',data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

If code is CHILD_1:

```
[{
    "label": "Grand Parent 1",
    "index": 0,
    "code": "GRAND_PARENT_1",
    "defaultCollapsed": true,
    "selected": true,
    "items": [{
        "id": 1,
        "items": [{
            "id": 100,
            "label": "Child 1",
            "url": "#CHILD_1",
            "code": "CHILD_1",
            "selected": true,
          },
          {
            "id": 200,
            "label": "Child 2",
            "url": "#CHILD_2",
            "code": "CHILD_2"
          },
          {
            "id": 300,
            "label": "Child 3",
            "url": "#CHILD_3",
            "code": "CHILD_3"
          },
          {
            "id": 400,
            "label": "Child 4",
            "url": "#CHILD_4",
            "code": "CHILD_4"
          }
        ],
        "defaultCollapsed": false,
        "label": "Parent 1",
        "selected": true,
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "items": [],
        "defaultCollapsed": true,
        "label": "Parent 2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "items": [],
        "defaultCollapsed": true,
        "label": "Parent 3"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "items": [],
        "defaultCollapsed": true,
        "label": "Parent 4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Grand Parent 2",
    "index": 1,
    "code": "GRAND_PARENT_2",
    "defaultCollapsed": true,
    "items": []
  },
  {
    "label": "Grand Parent 3",
    "index": 2,
    "code": "GRAND_PARENT_3",
    "defaultCollapsed": true,
    "items": []
  }
]
```

If the above output is the actual data, and the code is CHILD_1 again, I need to toggle the selected property of the child as well the corresponding parents.

```
[{
    "label": "Grand Parent 1",
    "index": 0,
    "code": "GRAND_PARENT_1",
    "defaultCollapsed": true,
    "selected": false,
    "items": [{
        "id": 1,
        "items": [{
            "id": 100,
            "label": "Child 1",
            "url": "#CHILD_1",
            "code": "CHILD_1",
            "selected": false,
          },
          {
            "id": 200,
            "label": "Child 2",
            "url": "#CHILD_2",
            "code": "CHILD_2"
          },
          {
            "id": 300,
            "label": "Child 3",
            "url": "#CHILD_3",
            "code": "CHILD_3"
          },
          {
            "id": 400,
            "label": "Child 4",
            "url": "#CHILD_4",
            "code": "CHILD_4"
          }
        ],
        "defaultCollapsed": false,
        "label": "Parent 1",
        "selected": false,
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "items": [],
        "defaultCollapsed": true,
        "label": "Parent 2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "items": [],
        "defaultCollapsed": true,
        "label": "Parent 3"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "items": [],
        "defaultCollapsed": true,
        "label": "Parent 4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Grand Parent 2",
    "index": 1,
    "code": "GRAND_PARENT_2",
    "defaultCollapsed": true,
    "items": []
  },
  {
    "label": "Grand Parent 3",
    "index": 2,
    "code": "GRAND_PARENT_3",
    "defaultCollapsed": true,
    "items": []
  }
]
```

Comment: what is with other items and a possible `selected: true` or `selected: false`?

Comment: By default as per out post from https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/104423033, if code is CHILD_1, selected property should be set to true on grandparent, parent and child and defaultCollapsed should be set to false on grandparent, parent and child. If CHILD_1 already has selected: true, sending CHILD_1 again should set selected property to false on grandparent, parent and child and defaultCollapsed should be set to true on grandparent, parent and child. Another case is that when CHILD_1 is true and CHILD_2 is sent, only CHILD_1 selected is false. But parent and grandparent and CHILD_2

Comment: should be true and defaultCollapsed should be false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating recursive function using `forEach` loop and passing array of parents down with recursion so that you can update its selected property.

```js
const data = [{"label":"Grand Parent 1","index":0,"code":"GRAND_PARENT_1","defaultCollapsed":true,"items":[{"id":1,"items":[{"id":100,"label":"Child 1","url":"#CHILD_1","code":"CHILD_1"},{"id":200,"label":"Child 2","url":"#CHILD_2","code":"CHILD_2"},{"id":300,"label":"Child 3","url":"#CHILD_3","code":"CHILD_3"},{"id":400,"label":"Child 4","url":"#CHILD_4","code":"CHILD_4"}],"defaultCollapsed":true,"label":"Parent 1","selected":true},{"id":2,"items":[],"defaultCollapsed":true,"label":"Parent 2"},{"id":3,"items":[],"defaultCollapsed":true,"label":"Parent 3"},{"id":4,"items":[],"defaultCollapsed":true,"label":"Parent 4"}]},{"label":"Grand Parent 2","index":1,"code":"GRAND_PARENT_2","defaultCollapsed":true,"items":[]},{"label":"Grand Parent 3","index":2,"code":"GRAND_PARENT_3","defaultCollapsed":true,"items":[]}]

function update(data, key, value, parents = []) {
  data.forEach(e => {
    if (e[key] === value) {
      if (parents.length) {
        e.selected = !e.selected;

        parents.forEach(p => {
          p.defaultCollapsed = !e.selected
          p.selected = e.selected
        })

        data.forEach(s => {
          if (s != e && s.selected) s.selected = false;
        });
      }
    }

    if (e.items && e.items.length) {
      update(e.items, key, value, [...parents, e])
    }
  })
}

update(data, 'code', 'CHILD_4')
update(data, 'code', 'CHILD_4')
update(data, 'code', 'CHILD_2')
update(data, 'code', 'CHILD_1')
console.log(data)
```

Comment: This doesnt add selected property to the parent.

Comment: It does add to the parent, do you mean grand-parent?

Comment: Yes, to parent and grand parent as well

Comment: Didn't you say that you want to keep parent selected value `true` even when you set child selected value to `false`?

Comment: I did, I rephrased the question before you posted your answer. My bad. Sorry about that. My requirement wasnt clear enough.

Comment: So when you toggle child to false all of its parents should also return to false?

Comment: Yes, I am changing the requirement a little bit as well. If another code is give, the previous code which has slected to true should become false. If selected property is true for the child, the chilld, parent and grandparent should have defaultCollapsed to false. I will update the OP. Thanks.

Comment: So why in your example `defaultCollapsed` on grand parent in still true in second and 3rd example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203272/discussion-between-a2441918-and-nenad-vracar).

Comment: Try this solution.

Comment: defaultCollapsed isnt set to true when I send in CHILD_1 again

Comment: Everything works well, but when child_1 selected is true and child_2 is sent in the function, expected result is child_1 selected is false and child_2 selected is true, but now sleected for child_1 and child_2 are both true

Comment: @a2441918 Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You could toggle the target node and leave the rest as true, for the path to the item.

```js
function update(array, value) {
    var found = false;
    array.forEach(o => {
        var sub = update(o.items || [], value),
            check = o.code === value;

        if (check) {
            o.selected = !o.selected
            found = o.selected;
        } else {
            o.selected = sub;
            if (sub) found = o.selected;
        }
        o.defaultCollapsed = !o.selected;
    });
    return found;
}

var data = [{ label: "Grand Parent 1", index: 0, code: "GRAND_PARENT_1", defaultCollapsed: true, items: [{ id: 1, items: [{ id: 100, label: "Child 1", url: "#CHILD_1", code: "CHILD_1" }, { id: 200, label: "Child 2", url: "#CHILD_2", code: "CHILD_2" }, { id: 300, label: "Child 3", url: "#CHILD_3", code: "CHILD_3" }, { id: 400, label: "Child 4", url: "#CHILD_4", code: "CHILD_4" }], defaultCollapsed: false, label: "Parent 1" }, { id: 2, items: [], defaultCollapsed: true, label: "Parent 2" }, { id: 3, items: [], defaultCollapsed: true, label: "Parent 3" }, { id: 4, items: [], defaultCollapsed: true, label: "Parent 4" }] }, { label: "Grand Parent 2", index: 1, code: "GRAND_PARENT_2", defaultCollapsed: true, items: [] }, { label: "Grand Parent 3", index: 2, code: "GRAND_PARENT_3", defaultCollapsed: true, items: [] }];

update(data, 'CHILD_1');
console.log(data);
update(data, 'CHILD_1');
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The parent still has selected true in the second output. The child as well the parent selected property should be toggled if the same property is passed in again

Comment: Perfect. One small change I need is that I need to update defaultCollapsed to false when the child selected is set to true. If child selected is false, defaultCollapsed on grandparent, parent and child should be set to true.

Comment: found = (o.selected = !o.selected); How can I fix this multiassign?